# MySQL Can't get FULLTEXT search to work

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I've been away from MySQL for quite some time and I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I got a simple query where I need to use FULLTEXT search:

`SELECT * FROM post WHERE MATCH ( title, content ) AGAINST ( 'Pytho*' )`

it doesn't return anything even though I got a lot of posts with Python in the title or content. If I go with full word it works:

`SELECT *  FROM post WHERE MATCH ( title, content ) AGAINST ( 'Python*' )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT * FROM post 
 WHERE MATCH ( title, content ) AGAINST ( 'Python' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```

[DEMO HERE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db225/1)

Comment: this surely works without even trying but it's not fulltext :)